# $\cos(a)+\cos(b)-\cos(a+b)\geq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, angle, geometric-inequalities

I am trying to prove that $$\cos(a)+\cos(b)-\cos(a+b)\geq 1$$ For $a,b \geq 0$ and $0\leq a+b\leq 180^°$

I have checked in Wolfram Alpha that the inequality is true, but I am not able to prove it. The trigonometric identitiy I have tried to apply (basically, $$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b))$$ does not seem useful as it is, so if there is some other one that you think it could help... any hint would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos a + \cos b - \cos(a+b) - 1 = 2\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2} - 2\cos^2\frac{a+b}{2} = 2\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\left(\cos\frac{a-b}{2} - \cos\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\geq 0.$$
The thing in the parenthesis is non-negative because $\cos$ decreases on $[0,\pi/2].$

Comment: thanks! I guessed there should be some useful trigonometric identity, but I focused only in the $\cos(a+b)$ one mentioned... great answer!

Comment: I am assuming this is probably enough to complete your other question.

Comment: Yes, it is! ;) I was just working in the answer, so I will credit to you this final piece I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The argument in the final line is shaky, it's possible for $(a-b)/2$ to be outside that range.

Comment: @SuzuHirose it's fine because then you flip the sign as $\cos$ is an even function.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Also we can assume wlog $a \ge b\ge 0$. Good point anyway.

Comment: @peterwhy I've implicitely assumed $a,b\ge 0$.

Comment: See peterwhy's comment under the question. If $a=180$ and $b=-180$ then $a+b=0$ but $a-b=360$ and $\cos (a-b)/2)=-1$, $\cos((a+b)/2)=1$ and the expression is -1.

Comment: @dezdichado,  Using https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html $$\cos\dfrac{a-b}2-\cos\dfrac{a+b}2=2\sin\dfrac a2\sin\dfrac b2$$ which is clearly $\ge0$  if $0\le a,b\le 360^\circ$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, assume $a$ fixed and $b=x\in\left[0, \pi-a\right]$ then we have by convexity

$$f(x)=\cos(a)+\cos(x)-\cos(a+x)-1\ge 0$$

indeed $f(0)=f(\pi -a)=0$ and for $x\in\left(0, \pi-a\right)$ we have

$$f''(x) =\cos (a+x)-\cos x\le 0$$

since $\cos$ is decreasing in $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$, we can rewrite

$$\begin{array}{crcl}
& \cos a+\cos b-\cos(a+b) & \le & 1 \\[2pt]
\iff & \cos a+\cos b-[\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b] & \le & 1 \\[2pt]
\iff & \sin a\sin b & \le & 1-\cos a-\cos b+\cos a\cos b \\[2pt]
\iff & \sin a\sin b & \le & (1-\cos a)(1-\cos b) \\[3pt]
\iff & 1 & \le & \displaystyle\frac{1-\cos a}{\sin a}\,\frac{1-\cos b}{\sin b} \\[3pt]
\iff & 1 & \le & \,\,\tan(a/2)\,\tan(b/2)
\end{array} $$

Since $0^\circ\le a/2+b/2\le90^\circ$ and $\tan$ is increasing on $[0^\circ,90^\circ]$, we can reason

$$ \tan(a/2)\tan(b/2) \,~\le~\, \tan(a/2)\tan(90^\circ-a/2) \,~=~\, 1, $$

so the claim is proved. (I guess handle the edge cases separately tho.)

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\cos a  + \cos b -\cos(a+b) - 1 = 2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) - 2\cos^2\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+1 -1= 2x\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)-2x^2=f(x), x = \cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$. We now show: $f(x) \ge 0$, or $2x^2 - 2x\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) \le 0$. Observe that $0 \le x \le \cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$, as a quadratic function in $x$, $f(x) \ge 0$.